# JSP Login form containing user/password & security group

Tags: java, jsp, security, tomcat

I have a general question about setting up a JSP (j_security_check) login form with the addition of an explicit security group drop-down option.

Currently my application is configured to using LDAP authentication within the security-realm of my server.xml in order to login to the index.jsp page, however I'm now looking to broaden the level(s) of access ranging from application.admin, application.limited, etc.

My web XML would contain the following security roles as well

```
<security-role>
<description>Admin Security Group</description>
<role-name>application.admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
<description>Limited Access Security Group</description>
<role-name>application.limited</role-name>
</security-role>
```

For testing purposes, I have a couple of test account users that assigned to the application.admin & application.limited security groups, so I'm seeing if I can expand on the login.jsp and assign the following fields.

**User** (Input Text Field)
**Password** (Input Text Field)

**Group** (Drop-Down Selection containing application.admin, application.limited)

```
<select id="Role">
<option>Select Role</option>
<option value="application.admin">Admin</option>
<option value="application.limited">Limited</option>
</select>
```

Basically I'm hoping this will validate against the security group selected explicitly from the drop down? Once the user is logged into the index.jsp I'm hoping to scope the user + security group they're logged in as in order to segregate the viewing/feature conditions thereafter.
Are there better solutions to handle multiple security roles?

Comment: If your users only have one role you don't need to add the select option. It is a job of the authentication layer to know which is the role of the user that logged in.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to go completely off topic, but I'm seeing if there's a way I can scope the user's security role once they have logged into the index.jsp page? If the user belongs to "application.admin", I'm trying to setup the JSP to consume both the user and their security role perhaps through a session scope if that's even possible?